# github markdown for block of code

Tags: github, markdown

The following code isn't formatting the stuff between the ``` as assembly code and I was wondering why. Thanks!

````
- here is an example of an appropriate input file


```
.text
main:
        la   $s0, A              # load variables A and B into registers
        lw   $s0, 0($s0)
        la   $s1, B
        lw   $s1, 0($s1)

        add  $s2, $s0, $s1       # calculate sum
        la   $s3, Sum            # assign result to Sum
        sw   $s2, 0($s3)

        sub  $s2, $s0, $s1       # calculate difference
        la   $s3, Diff           # assign result to Diff
        sw   $s2, 0($s3)
exit:
        li   $v0, 10             # system call to terminate program
        syscall                  # make call

.data
A:      .word   32
B:      .word   16
Sum:    .word    0
Diff:   .word    0
```

<h3>Output:</h3> a ASCII text file with the corresponding MIPS machine code. Here is the corresponding output file to the above input file
````

Comment: for "formatting" you mean "syntax highlighting"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their 'linguist' engine for syntax highlighting only knows so many languages; it seems that assembly code is not amongst those, as I can't seem to see any samples in their [linguist/samples](https://github.com/github/linguist/tree/master/samples) directory.

It should still display as a code block in monospaced font, however, if it's between the ``` tags.

Comment: This answer is out-of-date. As alexo_o explained below, you need to use the `assembly` specifier. `nasm` or `asm` would also work.

Answer (score 14):

For what it's worth, now (3 years after the question was asked), assembly seems to work like a charm

````
```assembly
.text
main:
        la   $s0, A              # load variables A and B into registers
        lw   $s0, 0($s0)
        la   $s1, B
        lw   $s1, 0($s1)
```
````

Answer (score 7):

Different markdown implementations may use different syntax highlighting strings.

Stackoverflow uses this javascript file: https://dev.sstatic.net/js/prettify-full.en.js

There is no support for assembly unfortunately.
According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348110/missing-syntax-highlighting-for-x86-assembly?noredirect=1&lq=1) meta question the list of supported languages on stackexchange are:

```
"bsh", "c", "cc", "cpp", "cs", "csh",
"cyc", "cv", "htm", "html", "java",
"js", "m", "mxml", "perl", "pl", "pm",
"py", "rb", "sh", "xhtml", "xml", "xsl"
```

Github uses this yaml file: https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml
The correct string is `assembly`

Discord:
A list of languages can be found here: https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/
for Intel x86 the relevant code is `x86asm`